# how to set the height of svg and the height of container in which is svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I have created a wave with svg. This wave is in a container. How can i set the height of the svg wave and the height of the container in which is the svg?

```
<div class="container">
<h1 class="innertext">
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit
</h1>
<svg class="one" viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <path d="M0,100 C150,200 350,0 500,100 L500,00 L0,0 Z" style="stroke: none; fill:#05aed9;"></path>
</svg>

<svg class="two" viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="yMinYMin meet">
    <path d="M0,100 C150,200 350,0 500,100 L500,00 L0,1 Z" style="stroke: none; fill:#1e90ff;"></path>
</svg>


<svg class= "three" viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="yMinYMin meet">
    <path d="M0,100 C150,200 350,0 500,100 L500,00 L0,1 Z" style="stroke: none; fill:#004681;"></path>
</svg>

</div>
```

And this is the style i use:

```
svg {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
svg.one {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
svg.two {
  margin-top: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
svg.three {
  margin-top: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.container {
  height: 800px;
}

.innertext {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

[image: It should look like image below]

How can i achieve this like pic above?

Comment: or change the numbers in the viewbox if you want a crop-like effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't set a height on the SVG so it's expanding to take up all the space it can based on the AspectRatio.

You'll need to assign a height and width and, I suspect, set `preserveAspectRatio` to `none`.

```css
svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

svg.one {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

svg.two {
  margin-top: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

svg.three {
  margin-top: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container {
  height: 800px;
}

.innertext {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="innertext">
    Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit
  </h1>
  <svg class="one" viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0,100 C150,200 350,0 500,100 L500,00 L0,0 Z" style="stroke: none; fill:#05aed9;"></path>
</svg>

  <svg class="two" viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0,100 C150,200 350,0 500,100 L500,00 L0,1 Z" style="stroke: none; fill:#1e90ff;"></path>
</svg>


  <svg class="three" viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0,100 C150,200 350,0 500,100 L500,00 L0,1 Z" style="stroke: none; fill:#004681;"></path>
</svg>

</div>
```